# KeyPressed in C# GUI

Tags: user-interface, c#-4.0, keypress, keydown, keyup

I'm trying to build a GUI application in C#. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010. I have a lot of buttons and I want to connect the keyboard with the buttons in the application. So when "w" is pressed (just for example) I want to activate a button. And I want while the key is held down the button to do its function multiple times. I've tried to do it with KeyPress, KeyDown and KeyUp but they didn't work. I want to make it like driving a car in NFS - while the arrow up is held down the car is moving forward but in this case while the current button is held down its function is executed.

Thank you in advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using some flags and timer.

When user presses "W" key, you will set flag as keyDown, and after that start the timer. On timer elapsed you can check for "keyDown" flag and do the assigned work for that key. OnKeyUp you reset the flag and stop the timer.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I think it will work but I was hoping that there's an easier way using the events they provided. : )

Comment: Got [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/6d305d65-7691-4e23-ab1d-cac4cf3d4ba4/) post from MSDN. It seems they are doing the same stuff :)